# Text highlighting within table row

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 4 columns and dynamic number of rows. Each row has multiple lines of text.  I'd like to highlight every other line of text (not every other row).  The number of lines in a row/cell is dynamic.  I have seen a lot of examples on how to highlight every other row in a table but i haven't been able to find any examples on how to highlight every other line of text within a row.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please share your codes for the table here

Comment: Please share your html markup and the css that affects the table.

Comment: Though the comments above are correct - we can't really do much without seeing any code at all - barring some JS that determines character width and attempts to calculate likely line-break indexes based on cell-width on every resize, I'm not sure this is going to be possible.